Not able to understand why there is an extra delete button

When adding the 1st task in the to do list the code generates an extra button but works fine when I add subsequent tasks, I am not sure where is the problem.
I am taking the tasks from the querySelector from the input placeholder and the date from the input date in the html file.
When the add button is clicked it would trigger the todo() that will carry out all the necessary required operations.


let tasks = [{
  task: '',
  date: ''
}];
let displayhtml = '';

function todo() {
  let inputEle = document.querySelector('.js-input');
  let inputEleDate = document.querySelector('.js-date');
  const date = inputEleDate.value;
  const task = inputEle.value;
  console.log(task);
  console.log(date);
  tasks.push({
    task: task,
    date: date
  });
  console.log(tasks);
  inputEle.value = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    const eletask = tasks[i].task;
    const eledate = tasks[i].date;
    let html = `
            <p>${eletask}   ${eledate} <button onclick="deleteToDo(${i})">Delete</button> </p>
            `;
    console.log(html);
    displayhtml += html;
    document.querySelector('.js-display').innerHTML = displayhtml;
  }
  displayhtml = ''
};

function deleteToDo(i) {
  tasks.slice(i, 1)
  console.log(tasks)
}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To-do List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./todo.css">
  <p>To Do List</p>
  <input class="js-input" placeholder="Add any task to the list">
  <input type="date" class="js-date">
  <button onclick="
    todo()
    ">Add</button>
  <div class="js-display">
  </div>
  <script src="./todo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Isn't it obvious?  You create your tasks array with one valid task, with an empty name.  Just do let tasks = [];.

Ok so instead to initialising it as object from the the start, I should initialise it as any normal array. Thanks it worked!

Right.  It's NOT an object.  It's an array.  The contents are irrelevant at initialization.

In todo.js we initialize the tasks array with empty object
tasks=[{
    task:'',
    date:''
}];

and then we pushing the new data in that tasks array so now it has 2 values in the array.
Try
let tasks=[];

instead of
let tasks=[{
    task:'',
    date:''
}];

